# Cannot create file "c:\User\...\Appdata\Roaming...". Access is denied

Tags: c#, .net

I want to store certain .txt file during app lifetime. I was thinking to use `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`

so I created

```
 string myFilename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), address.GetHashCode() + ".txt");
...
 File.WriteAllText(myFilename, someTextContent);
```

I'm getting

> **Cannot create file "c:\User...\Appdata\Roaming...". Access is denied.**

Comment: Do you need to write there?  Can you write to the temp directory ( think it's `Path.GetTempDirectory()` ) or somewhere else?

Comment: How is your code executing?  Is it a command line running under your windows account?  Is it a windows service?  An IIS hosted web site running as a service account?

Comment: @PhilipPittle it's a simple wpf app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy(v=vs.110).aspx), you have guaranteed read/write access with it.

Writing:

```
IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetStore(IsolatedStorageScope.User | IsolatedStorageScope.Assembly, null, null);
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TestStore.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, isoStore))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(isoStream))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Hello Isolated Storage");
    }
}
```

Reading:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TestStore.txt", FileMode.Open, isoStore))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(isoStream))
    {
        string contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```